# Number of permutations of 100 data points is larger than number of atoms in universe?

Tags: statistics, permutations

I found different resources on this topic and therefore my question. Can someone tell is number of permutations od $100$ data points larger than number of atoms in universe?

I got this question from my statistics course and unfortunately $0$ material to that.

Comment: So perhaps by permutations of 100 you mean $100!$ which is roughly $9\times 10^{157}$ ... ? Yeah, I think it's more than the number of atoms ...

Comment: [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation).As for the number of atoms in the _entre_ Universe, I don't think it is known, but there are estimates for the _observable_ universe: somewhere around $10^{80}$ (however, I don't know of an authoritative source to point to).

Comment: @StinkingBishop; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddington_number

Comment: To emphasize what has been said : We can estimate only the number of atoms in the observable universe ! We cannot know what is and whether there is something "behind" it. And of course, this estimate is very rough and also speculative. But we can safely assume that it is FAR below $100!$ as pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean permutations on 100 values, as in how many different functions exist :
$f:{[1,...,100]}\rightarrow{[1,...,100]}$

So the answer would be 100! after you choose one element you have 99 more elements to place in 99 places.
I would think the term number of atoms in the universe is referring to the concept of combinatorial explosion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion

But the general idea is there are about $10^{82}$ atoms.
If you wish to compare $100!>10^{82}$, I would try to see for which exponent of 10 we get a good approx. or which factorial gives us a good estimate of $10^{82}$.

Answer (score 0):

As @Nadav stated, the estimate of the atoms in the Universe is $10^{82}$. Here's an awful approximation of $100!$, that still does the job:
$$\text{#Permutation}=100!>\frac{100!}{9!}=100\cdot99\cdot98\cdots11\cdot10>10^{91}>10^{82}=\text{#Atoms}$$